# "Not a real question" close reason?

Tags: discussion

Was the "Not a real question" close reason:

[image]

Replaced with "Unclear what you're asking"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it was.  Background is in these Meta Stack Exchange posts:

[Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)

[Help us make “Not Constructive” and “Not a Real Question” closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)